# Laravel 4 how to return multiple view data with ajax and json?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, laravel

Basically I'm trying to make a popup using this ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET'
    url: 'news/read'
    dataType: 'json'
    cache: false
    timeout: 10000
}).done (msg) ->
    $("article#pop-read").empty().html msg.view
    processing = false
    window.history.pushState
        path: msg.url
        , "", msg.url
    false
```

And I'm returning a view value and it's url with this:

```
$data = json_encode(array(
        'view' => View::make('layouts.read'),
    'url' => 'news/read/2013/11/24/test-title-seperate-with-dash'
));
return $data;
```

This all works really well except that I can't get the view value from laravel (it returns `Object object` in javascript). But it returns nicely if I directly write it like `return View::make('layouts.read')`. Why is that?

Additionally (don't have to answer, not primary question), the back button on my browser doesn't work when I use `pushState`, is it a bug?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may try this

```
$data = json_encode(array(
    'view' => (String)View::make('layouts.read'),
    'url' => 'news/read/2013/11/24/test-title-seperate-with-dash'
));
return $data;
```

Also, you can use

```
View::make('layouts.read')->render();
View::make('layouts.read')->__toString();
```

Also, `Laravel` provides `Response::json()` method for same reason (instead of `json_encode`).

Comment: ok, thanks, all solutions worked. Moving on to `pushState` problem now.

Comment: any idea how to parse the view into the json response? how to give the html of the view to an element in my page using $('#element').html(data.html) ?

Comment: Post a question, gimme the link and I'll answer, be specific with details in the question.